# Xcode SpriteKit Designer Clear Background Red X

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm not sure what the issue is, but I'm trying to design a level in Apple's Sprite Kit editor, and I'm running into a problem with SKSpriteNodes that have a transparent background. Sometimes the background doesn't appear as clear. Instead, SpriteKit seems to load a Red X as a background image.

Naturally, I can't have this. Also, it's a problem because I really should be doing all of the level design in the editor instead of manually adding sprites in my Scene code.

Has anyone come across this problem? Could it be a bug in SpriteKit Designer? (There are a number of issues I've had with it since starting to use the tool).

Here is a photo of what it looks like:
[image: I have set the background to 'clear' for those sprites.]

Comment: The white square with red x is a default placeholder for when an image or texture is not loaded.

Comment: Okay. But what if I don't want to load an image? I'm trying to have a clear sprite that represents a physics boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a kinda hacky way to solve it. Basically, as uchuugaka said, the Red X appears when Sprite Kit fails to load a texture. If you want a clear background, you have to load a clear png file as the background of the sprite. There is no "No Texture" option currently available in the Sprite Kit designer.

Take these steps.

1.) Open any .png file with some transparency in it.

2.) Copy an arbitrary rectangular section of pixels.

3.) Create a new file with said arbitrary pixels.

4.) Save this file as your "clear.png" and import it into your project.

5.) Click on the sprite node with the Big Red X so you can see its setting. Take a screenshot of its position, size, etc. using preview. These settings will get erased when you swap the texture over to clear.png

6.) Swap the texture to clear.png

7.) Re-enter the sprite settings from your screenshot.

8.) Because SpriteKit Editor is currently horribly terribly flawed (see post above), you will need to reset your sprite's physics properites. Set the physics body to none. Then set it to bounding box or circle or alpha mask or whatever you had earlier.

9.) I hope you remembered your collision mask, category mask, and other physics body properties because they just got reset to the default. Re-enter what you had earlier or you will get a very unexpected result.

Comment: Remember the class hierarchy, any SKNode or subclass of SKNode can have a physics body. It doesn't need to be an SKSpriteNode

Comment: I personally gave up on the graphical editor during the beta, it crashed too much for me. I found it was fine to write code. Hopefully the editor will continue to improve, then it will be better.